# Radio buttons not showing at first page load

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button

Have you any idea why the radio buttons are not showing when the page loads? I am using angular material mat-radio-buttons.

[image: Radio buttons]

[CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esrgod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added `formControlName` to both `mat-radio-group` and `mat-radio-button` elements, while it should only be added to the `mat-radio-group`:

```html
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  formControlName="seasonsForm"
>
  <mat-radio-button
    class="example-radio-button"
    *ngFor="let season of seasons"
    [value]="season"
  >
    {{ season }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esrgod-vv32ds?file=src/app/child/child.component.html)